# Making fixed position div stop when reaching footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a side menu `(.link-panel)`. Inside `.link-panel` is a div `(.cover)` that hold the contents of the `.link-panel`. `.cover` is a fixed div so that the links can move when the user scrolls. The only problem I am facing is that I have a footer at the bottom, and whenever I scroll down the `cover` div goes on top of the `.footer`. I am trying to make it so that the `.cover` stops when it reaches the footer. That way the `.footer` and `.cover` don't overlap. I have tried using some jQuery in order to solve this, but my technique is not working. It's producing very weird results. Sometimes, some of the links are above the window and can't be shown, other times when you scroll down to the `.footer`, the `.link-panel` does not go up again when you scroll. You can see and experiment [here with the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z1hb1s2/) I created.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class='control_panel'>
    <div class='control_title'>
      <h2>Your Settings</h2>
    </div>

    <div class='control_settings'>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="link-panel">
  <div class="cover">


    <ul>


      <li> Dashboard</li>
      <hr>
      <li> Blog</li>
      <hr>
      <li><span><b>|</b> Settings</span></li>
      <hr>
      <li> Contact Us</li>


    </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!--End of link panel div-->
</div>

<div class='footer'>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.control_panel {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.control_title {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.control_settings {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 900px;
  width: 900px;
}

.link-panel {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.cover{
   position: fixed;
}
.link-panel ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.link-panel li {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function checkOffset() {
  var a=$(document).scrollTop()+window.innerHeight;
  var b=$('.footer').offset().top;
  if (a<b) {
    $('.cover').css('bottom', '-14');
  } else {
    $('.cover').css('bottom', (-14+(a-b))+'px');
  }
}
$(document).ready(checkOffset);
$(document).scroll(checkOffset);
```

How do I make it so that `.cover` moves up and down when the user scrolls, but stops when it reaches the `.footer`, but when the user scrolls up again so does the `.cover`?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: hopefully now it works on Chrome too.

I've made a fiddle for your case: https://jsfiddle.net/g8ctha2o/5/

Tell me if it works for you.

Basically what you do is you check on the scroll event that the bottom edge of the menu has a smaller position value than the top edge of the footer. Once this is no longer true, you reach a scroll threshold in which you change its position from fixed to absolute with jQuery.

```
var menuBottom,
  footerTop = $('.footer').offset().top,
  positionChanged = false,
  scrollThreshold;

$('.scrollable').on('scroll', function() {
  menuBottom = $('.scrollable').scrollTop() + $('.menu').offset().top + $('.menu').outerHeight();
  if (!positionChanged) {
    if (menuBottom + 5 >= footerTop) {
      scrollThreshold = $('.scrollable').scrollTop();
      $('.menu').css({
        visibility: 'hidden',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: menuBottom - $('.menu').outerHeight() - 5,
        right: 35,
        visibility: 'visible'
      });
      positionChanged = true;
    }
  } else {
    if (scrollThreshold > $('.scrollable').scrollTop()) {
      $('.menu').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 450,
        right: 60
      });
      positionChanged = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This technique overlaps the menu with the footer, even in the jsfiddle. Also it does not let you scroll down fully. When I implement your solution in my code, and try to scroll back up once I reach the footer, the menu does not go back up fully. I want the menu to stop when it reaches the footer and move when the user scrolls back up.

Comment: @user2896120 Strange, in Firefox is working perfectly. I've just tried it on Chrome and is not working. I'll look it up.

Comment: @user2896120 Can you tell me if it works for you now?

Comment: Hmm, this won't work for me because `.footer` is dynamically added in my project, so it won't be inside any container like `.scrollable` Also, for some reason when you scroll down real quick in your jsfiddle, the menu overlaps the footer